# 'The underlying provider failed on Open' C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Tenho uma aplicação que possui 4 camadas, que são as seguintes : `Dominio, Infra, Servico, Web`  na dominio eu tenho uma pasta chamda `Poco` com todas as minhas `Classes/Tabelas` , na Camada `Infra`, para testar o `CodeFirst` eu creiei um objeto e dei `Servico.Add(Obejto)` para salvar no banco , mas qundo tenta acessar o banco eu tenho o seguinte erro de volta :

`'The underlying provider failed on Open'`

e dentro dessa exceptio tenho outra que diz o seguinte :

> "Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o
>   SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível.
>   Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está
>   configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL
>   Server)

E ainda tem mais uma :

> "O caminho da rede não foi encontrado"

A minha conection string que se chama `Contexto` no Server Explorer mostra como conexão aberta.

```
<add name="Contexto" connectionString="DataSource=494.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;
Initial Catalog=db49c6a5011d0751;
Persist Security Info=True;
User ID="*";Password="*";MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient
```

O dados do Servidor foram alterados para segurança, Estou usando uma instãncia do appHarbor que esta vazia de qualquer forma, se for preciso postar os dados reias .

eu tenho o meu `Contexto`  que esta declarado da seguinte forma:

```
 public class Contexto : DbContext, IDisposable
{ 
   //Essas são apenas algumas das Classes/Tabelas 

    public DbSet<AdministradorUnidade> AdministradorUnidade { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoriaEspecialidade> CategoriaEspecialidade { get; set;}
    public DbSet<CategoriaTratamento> CategoriaTratamento { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoriaVideoParceiro> CategoriaVideoParceiro { get; set;}
    public DbSet<CategoriaVideoServico> CategoriaVideoServico { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cidade> Cidade { get; set; }



    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }


}
```

Tenho também nessa pasta `DataBaseFactory` e `UnitOfWork`(Caso necessário eu posto essas também)

Minha Connection string com o banco de dados esta correta , seu eu for em `View -> Server Explorer` e colocar a conexão esta feita aberta, mas mesmo assim ainda continuo tento este problema.

Comment: Verifique se o seu usuário do IIS tem acesso ao seu BD. Para teste: remova o USER e PASSWORD da sua connection string e ajuste o BD para aceitar assim. Se der certo é este o seu problema.

Comment: Vou testar aqui , mas eu consigo acessar o banco pelo Sql Management Studio, mas vou fazer o teste para você.

Comment: ´{"This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection."}´´

Comment: Deu esse erro agora KKK

Comment: Quando eu removo o usario e senha a conexao no server explorer fecha automaticamente

Comment: Sim, você tem que deixar seu BD sem autenticação de usuário e senha.
Crie um BD a parte que não tenha usu e senha, e coloque ele na connection string.

Comment: Entendi, esse Bd esta Hospedado no AppHarbor , vou ver como faço essas alterações la.

Comment: Uma possível solução: 

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/126919/Solution-for-The-underlying-provider-failed-on-Ope

Comment: Não resolvei o post , e aparentemente o AppHarbor não deixa retirar senha e usuario, já que é padrão .

Comment: Crie um BD separado...  Uma resposta a cima tem outra dica, você chegou a tentar ela ?

Comment: Seu Initial Catalog está correto?

Comment: Estava sim , eu na verdade não sei qual e o problema, acho que era problema com o servidor e não com o codigo, agora funciona normalmente. Mas não sei o que resolveu o meu problema.